# Generalise ImageLines to Image3DPlanes?

Tags: image-processing, geometry, peak-detection

**Context**

I am interested in detecting (multiple) planes in a cube.

**Test case**

Let me first define a test case:

```
n = 32;
dat = Array[0 # &, {n, n, n}];
dat[[;; , ;; , n/2]] = 1;
(img=Image3D[dat]) // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

Now I can  nicely detect Lines in 2D via `ImageLines` in a section of this cube.

```
lines = (im1 = dat[[;; , n/2, ;;]] // Image) // 
   ImageLines[#, MaxFeatures -> 1, Method -> "RANSAC"] &;

HighlightImage[im1, lines]
```

[image]

**Question**

> How could I generalise this to detecting Planes in the 3D cube?

Specifically, how could one write a `Image3DPlanes` function which would generalise `ImageLines`  such that

```
 Image3DPlanes[img]
```

returns a set of planes?

Note that these planes are not necessarily perpendicular to the axes.

PS: Note that `ImageLines[im1, MaxFeatures -> 1]` does not do a great job with the default method.

Comment: Interesting problem! Have you looked at any papers on the subject? e.g [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221209055_Detection_of_Planar_Regions_in_Volume_Data_for_Topology_Optimization) or [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228754371_The_3D_Hough_Transform_for_plane_detection_in_point_clouds_A_review_and_a_new_accumulator_design)

Comment: Maybe the [3D Radon Transform](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amir1/PS/3DRadon.pdf) could help - unfortunately Mathematica only has a 2D one, but perhaps a CUDA/OpenCL implementation is possible.

Comment: @flinty thanks for the links